# How to implement a forward ref in React0.14?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

I want to get the ref of the children's component.The nested relationship between the components is shown below：

```
<Demo1 /> ---> <Demo2 /> ---> <Demo3 />
```

how to get the ref of Demo3 in Demo1?

Comment: It may be difficult to get help with a React version that's 7 years old. I don't think you can even get to the documentation for versions < 15. Your real problem to solve may be updating your code base to support a newer version of React.

Comment: Because I need to be compatible with IE8, I have to use low version of react

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `ref` inside of the `props`:

```
// -- sub-sub component
var SubSub = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div><sub ref={ this.props.subSubRef }>Sub-sub component</sub></div>;
    }
});

// -- sub component
var Sub = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div><em>Sub component</em><SubSub subSubRef={ this.props.subRef } /></div>;
    }
});

// -- root component
var Main = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

        // -- get the ref from the child
        const refCallback = function( domRef ){
            this._subSubDomRef = domRef;
        }.bind( this );

        // -- example: accessing the dom element in some way
        const handleClick = function(){
            if( this._subSubDomRef ){
                this._subSubDomRef.innerHTML = this._subSubDomRef.innerHTML + '.';
            }
        }.bind( this );

        // --
        return <div>
            <strong onClick={ handleClick }>Main component</strong>
            <Sub subRef={ refCallback } />
        </div>;
    }
});
```

*(Note that you might run into conflicts in the case that some library that you are using, uses the same prop name as you do. That's one reason why `forwardRef` is recommended)*

#### Further information:

The **official React documentation** mentions forwarding refs prior to the availability of `forwardRef`
under [exposing-dom-refs-to-parent-components](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#exposing-dom-refs-to-parent-components),
and recommends the example in [dom_ref_forwarding_alternatives_before_16.3.md](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/1a018a023347fe1c2476073330cc5509#file-dom_ref_forwarding_alternatives_before_16-3-md).

Unfortunately this example uses `createRef`, which is also not available before v16.3.
You need to follow the comments there and adapt the example accordingly.

The **React documentation for v0.14** can be found at [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20151027102557/http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html).

`forwardRef` and `createRef` were introduced in version **16.3.0** (March 29, 2018):

- 2018-02-06 createRef (8dc8f88d5ae9fb96934ba43e3842b5dcf4074afd)
- 2018-03-14 forwardRef 16.3.0-alpha.2 (bc70441c8b3fa85338283af3eeb47b5d15e9dbfe)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a good way, but if the component level is deep, this is a disaster.I want to have a more elegant way to realize it.

Comment: Passing the `ref` through deeply nested components with `forwardRef` is the same disaster, IMO (your question was _"implement a forward ref in React0.14"_). I suppose it is not possible to do it more elegant in React 14, without the new features available. Only in a different, equally hacky way, maybe. You probably can store a `ref` in the state, which is surely not recommended. I don't know what to consider if you want to do it anyway though. Also don't know when the `context` API were implemented.